# Preserving sequential order of numpy 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sequential

Given this 2D `numpy` array:

```
a=numpy.array([[31,22,43],[44,55,6],[17,68,19],[12,11,18],...,[99,98,97]])
```

given the need to flatten it using [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
b=numpy.ravel(a)
```

and given the need to later dump it into a `pandas` dataframe, **how can I make sure the sequential order of the values in `a` is preserved when applying `numpy.ravel`?** e.g., How can I check/ensure that `numpy.ravel` does not mess up with the original sequential order?

Of course the intended result should be that the numbers coming before and after `17` in `b`, for instance, are the same as in `a`.

Comment: What do you mean by `maintining sequential order of the values`? Could you use a smaller sample and show us the expected o/p? Do you mean `a.ravel('F')`?

Comment: Well I have of course used fake values to make the case. The intended outcome is that, once `a` is flattened, the values coming before and after `17` are still the same as in `a`.

Comment: What's before `17` in `a`?  It's the first value in its row.  Is 44 before it, or 6?  You have to do some advanced stuff like transpose or weird indexing to change the raveled order.

Comment: @hpaulj In my intentions it is `6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to formulate what "sequential" order means for you, as `numpy.ravel()` does preserve order. Here is a tip how to formulate what you need: try with a simplest possible toy example:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.arange(20).reshape(-1,4)

X
#array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#   [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#   [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
#   [12, 13, 14, 15],
#   [16, 17, 18, 19]])
X.ravel()
# array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 
#        13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
```

Does it meet your expectation? Or you want to see this order:

```
Z = X.T
Z
# array([[ 0,  4,  8, 12, 16],
#        [ 1,  5,  9, 13, 17],
#        [ 2,  6, 10, 14, 18],
#        [ 3,  7, 11, 15, 19]])
Z.ravel()
# array([ 0,  4,  8, 12, 16,  1,  5,  9, 13, 17,  2,  6, 10, 
#         14, 18,  3,  7, 11, 15, 19])
```